# How to create navigation arrow in Owl carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, owl-carousel

I am struggling to implement the very basic features of Owl Carousel.  In my carousel user  can only browse  the slides by select and hold one image and drag.  it gives no hints to the user that there are more images which they can actually browse and drag.   All I want is to put a previous/ next arrow so people can click the arrow and to view more images in the carousel. But I am struggling to do that probably because the carousel implemented in a complicated way.

My site is on Wordpress but the Owl carousel plugin has not been used. Its been implemented manually. The images in the carousel are fetched from the database.

This is how the carousel getting the images . File name shortcode.php

```
function carousel_register( $atts, $content = null ) {

extract(shortcode_atts(array(
  'group_id' => ''
), $atts));

if(isset($group_id)){
    $to_add = '?g='.$group_id[0];
}else{
    $to_add = '';
}



$output = '<section id="carousel" class=""><div class="container" align="center"><h2>Simply Choose Your Agent</h2><div id="agents-carousel" class="agents-carousel">';

foreach ($data_json['data'] as $k => $v) {

        if ($v['onlinestatus'] == 1) {
            $online = "Online";
        }
        if ($v['onlinestatus'] == 0) {
            $online = "Offline";
        }

        $name = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9]/", "", $v['display_name']);

        $output .= '<div class="item"><a href="'.get_site_url().'/'.strtolower($v['display_name']).'"><div class="image-carousel"><img src="'.get_site_url().'/profile-image/medium/'.$v['id_user'].'/'.$name.'.png"></div></a></div>';
}
$output .='</div><div class="cta"><a href="'.get_site_url().'/our-readers/">discover all readers</a></div></div></section>';
return $output;

   }


add_shortcode( 'carousel', 'carousel_register' );
```

there are nearly 25 images only 5 of them are showing. They can be dragged by grabbing them. All I want to add navigation arrows and dots .

```
.owl-carousel .owl-wrapper:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
    line-height: 0;
    height: 0; }
 .owl-carousel{
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
   -ms-touch-action: pan-y;}
.owl-carousel .owl-wrapper{
    display: none;
    position: relative;
   -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);}
.owl-carousel .owl-wrapper-outer{
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;}
.owl-carousel .owl-wrapper-outer.autoHeight{
    -webkit-transition: height 500ms ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: height 500ms ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: height 500ms ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: height 500ms ease-in-out;
    transition: height 500ms ease-in-out;}
   .owl-carousel .owl-item{
    float: left;}
.owl-controls .owl-page, .owl-controls .owl-buttons div{
    cursor: pointer;}
.owl-controls {
   -webkit-user-select: none;
   -khtml-user-select: none;
   -moz-user-select: none;
   -ms-user-select: none;
   user-select: none;
   -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);}
.grabbing {
    cursor:url(grabbing.png) 8 8, move;}
.owl-carousel .owl-wrapper, .owl-carousel .owl-item{
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);}
```

The css file is referenced in the header and the javascript file is referenced in the footer.

Edit : I have set value 0 for navigation in the javascript file. Now the arrow have been appeared. But they appeared in the center o the carousel. How to put them in the correct place i.e previous arrow in the left side of the carousel and next arrow in the right side of the carousel.

```
a.fn.owlCarousel.options = {
    items: 5,
    itemsCustom: !1,
    itemsDesktop: [ 1199, 4 ],
    itemsDesktopSmall: [ 979, 3 ],
    itemsTablet: [ 768, 2 ],
    itemsTabletSmall: !1,
    itemsMobile: [ 479, 1 ],
    singleItem: !1,
    itemsScaleUp: !1,
    slideSpeed: 200,
    paginationSpeed: 800,
    rewindSpeed: 1e3,
    autoPlay: !0,
    stopOnHover: !1,
    navigation: !0,
    navigationText: [ "prev", "next" ],
    rewindNav: !0,
    scrollPerPage: !1,
    pagination: !0,
    paginationNumbers: !1,
    responsive: !0,
    responsiveRefreshRate: 200,
    responsiveBaseWidth: b,
    baseClass: "owl-carousel",
    theme: "owl-theme",
    lazyLoad: !1,
    lazyFollow: !0,
    lazyEffect: "fade",
    autoHeight: !1,
    jsonPath: !1,
    jsonSuccess: !1,
    dragBeforeAnimFinish: !0,
    mouseDrag: !0,
    touchDrag: !0,
    addClassActive: !1,
    transitionStyle: !1,
    beforeUpdate: !1,
    afterUpdate: !1,
    beforeInit: !1,
    afterInit: !1,
    beforeMove: !1,
    afterMove: !1,
    afterAction: !1,
    startDragging: !1,
    afterLazyLoad: !1
};
```

Comment: I refer you to use Slick instead of Owl http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

Comment: Slick is awesome. But 99%work has been done with owl carousel. . and as these images are also coming from 3rd party api its really complicated to implement. All I need is the arrows now.

Comment: Lot of jQuery error showing on your website console i think that is why its not working

Comment: @Bashabi, its small change you need to do. Slick is the correct one.

Comment: Hi I have edited my question. I manged to get the navigation arrow but not in ideal position. If possible please assist me to solve this issue

Comment: HI,

used something like this in owl carousal

nav: true,
 navText : ["<i class='fa fa-chevron-left'></i>","<i class='fa fa-chevron-right'></i>"],

you can also use custom img tags.

but in your case I think you can use this in this "navigationText: [ "prev", "next" ],"

Comment: something like this 
navigationText: [<i class='fa fa-chevron-left'></i>","<i class='fa fa-chevron-right'></i> ],

Comment: or  navigationText: ["<img src="left.png">","<img src="right.png">"],

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I give you a example but i used owl carousal 2

here

```
var heroSlider = $('#header-slider');
heroSlider.owlCarousel({    
    margin:0,
    autoplay:true,
    autoplayTimeout:4000,
    smartSpeed:2000,
    dots:true,
    loop:true,      
    responsiveClass:true,
    items:1,
    rtl: true,
    nav: true,
     navText : ["<i class='fa fa-chevron-left'></i>","<i class='fa fa-chevron-right'></i>"],

});
```

for the correct position we need to set the positions of the arrows.By styling them.

something like this

```
.owl-prev {
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
}

.owl-next {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}
```